# Calling a Recursive CTE on every record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I have a stored procedure query that returns all electrical panels in relation to their position to a given electrical circuit. To make the query as informative as possible I also return the loading (sum of circuits power requirement) on each panel and the quantity of circuits used.

The sum of loading of each panel has to take into account a parent child relationship between panels, as some panels supply other panels which also have load.

To achieve this parent child load calculation I use a recursive CTE which works well to find the load of 1 panel. However, when I want to use the first query, it calls the CTE calculation query on every row, resulting in a significant performance hit.

What is the best practice in order to speed up this query? I have tried table value functions which have helped but I feel that I require a completely different approach.

Main query

```
SELECT p.Panel,
       (ABS(gcX.COOR -t.TX) + ABS(gcY.COOR -t.TY)) / 1000 AS Length,
       'TBD' AS Load,
       'TBD' AS [Available Circuits],
       ROUND(v.kVA / p.kVA * 100, 0) AS LOAD,
       p.[Status],
       p.PanelID
  FROM 
  (
     SELECT poc.*,
            tc.X,
            tc.Y
       FROM tblPowerCircuits poc   
       LEFT JOIN SI_EquipCoordinates tc
         ON poc.EntityCode = tc.Entity_Code
            AND  poc.Life = tc.Life
      WHERE poc.POCID = @POCID
  )t
  INNER JOIN tblPanels p
     ON t.utility = p.Utility
        AND t.train = p.train
        AND t.Filt = p.Filt
        AND p.BP_DP =
            CASE 
                WHEN t.FLA < 61 THEN 1
                ELSE 2
            END
        AND p.voltage =
            CASE
              WHEN t.voltage = 230 THEN 400
              WHEN t.voltage = 120 THEN 208
              ELSE t.voltage
            END
   LEFT JOIN SI_GridCoordinates gcX
     ON p.x = gcX.GRID
        AND p.Facility = gcX.FAB   
   LEFT JOIN SI_GridCoordinates gcY
     ON p.y = gcY.GRID
        AND p.Facility = gcY.FAB   
  CROSS APPLY dbo.fnPH_GetPanelLoad(p.PanelID)v
  WHERE p.VisibleToFilter = 1
  ORDER BY Length, panel
```

Load per panel query

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER function [dbo].[fnPH_GetPanelLoad](
@PanelID int
)
returns table
as

return
( Select vpc.SourceID, round((Sum(poc.KVA * (CASE WHEN vpc.BP_DP = 1 THEN 0.8 * POWER(CAST(0.8 AS float), Depth) WHEN vpc.BP_DP = 2 THEN 0.64 * POWER(CAST(0.8 AS float), Depth) END))),0) as kVA from vwPanelClosure vpc join
PH_PanelCircuits pc on vpc.PanelID = pc.PanelID join
(Select * from PH_POCPanJoin where Active = 1) pj on pc.PanCctID = pj.PanCctID join
(SELECT        POCID, Circuit, L,F, KVA, Active
                               FROM            dbo.tblPowerCircuits) AS poc ON pj.POCID = poc.POCID LEFT OUTER JOIN                
                             (SELECT        Circuit, InstallDate,DemoDate
                               FROM            dbo.PH_POC_InstallDeinstallDate) AS s ON poc.Circuit = s.[Circuit] AND poc.L= s.L where (s.DemoDate > Dateadd(d,830,getdate()) or s.DemoDate is null) and vpc.sourceID = @PanelID
 group by

vpc.SourceID)
```

And here is the recursive query vwPanelClosure

```
WITH category_cte AS (SELECT        PanelID AS SourceID, PanelID, BP_DP, 0 AS depth
                                                  FROM            dbo.tblPanels
                                                  UNION ALL
                                                  SELECT        CTE.SourceID, C.PanelID, C.BP_DP, CTE.depth + 1 AS depth
                                                  FROM            dbo.tblPanels AS C INNER JOIN
                                                                           category_cte AS CTE ON C.SCID = CTE.PanelID)
    SELECT        SourceID, PanelID, BP_DP, depth
     FROM            category_cte AS category_cte_1
```

Should I be using something like a #Temp table to store the CTE values for repeat processing?

Comment: You can write a TVF to count what you need for any PanelID (with recursive CTE), then you join your table with that function on PanelID and get all possible Panells properties you need.

Comment: Why? Use `category_cte` in the same way you're using template tables!

Comment: I see the the TVF method you have stated is probably how I need to do it. Could you give me a sample of how this would work?

Comment: RE "Should I be using something like a #Temp": Yes. The query is slow because of two things: `CROSS APPLY dbo.fnPH_GetPanelLoad()` executing a relatively complex query for every PanelID and a call to a recursive CTE puts the last nail in the coffin. It will improve performance dramatically if you run a CTE once to calculate results for all PanelIDs and save it to #table or a @table. Do the same with the function.